Remove options in pydantic if they are already choosen
I want to create a voting app using FastUI.
In this app there are multiple countries to rank. If a country is selected for a rank it should disappear in the selection.
Is there a way to do this? So far I added a validator to check after the fields are set:
class VoteForm(BaseModel):
    rank_1: Literal[tuple(countries)] = Field(title="Rank #1")
    rank_2: Literal[tuple(countries)] = Field(title="Rank #2")
    rank_3: Literal[tuple(countries)] = Field(title="Rank #3")
    

    @model_validator(mode="after")
    def ensure_once(self) -> Self:
        input_set = set([self.rank_1, self.rank_2, self.rank_3])
        if len(input_set) < 3:
            raise ValueError("Choose each country only once")
        return self

